7-point North-East ILU decomposition
I am using a 7-point difference operator (actually a 5-point difference operator with $b, f = 0$) to discretize the 2D model anisotropic problem. $ L_h $ in stencil notation is given. $ L_h = \begin{bmatrix}
f & g & \cdot \\
c & d & q \\
\cdot & a & b
\end{bmatrix} $, where $a, b, c, d, q, f, g$ are constants, $ Nx = Ny $ and $ I = Nx - 1 $.
The grid is $ (0,1)^{2} $ and the ordering of the grid points is in the North-East direction. That is, column-wise bottom to top, left to right. The matrix formed by $ L_h $ is $ A $. Now, I am trying the 7-point North-East ILU decomposition for $ A $. That is,
$ L = \begin{bmatrix}
\zeta & \cdot & \cdot \\
\gamma & \delta & \cdot \\
\cdot & \alpha & \cdot
\end{bmatrix} $,
$ U = \begin{bmatrix}
\cdot & \eta & \cdot \\
\cdot & \delta & \mu \\
\cdot & \cdot & \beta
\end{bmatrix} $.
$ A = LD^{-1}U - R $, where $ L, D, U $ all have the same diagonal and $ R $ is the error matrix.
Now $ LD^{-1}U $ comes out to be weird, at least for me.
$ LD^{-1}U = \begin{bmatrix}
D9 & \cdot & \cdot \\
D7 & D8 & \cdot \\
D4 & D5 & D6 \\
\cdot & D2 & D3 \\
\cdot & \cdot & D1
\end{bmatrix} $.
$ D_{4} = \gamma_{k} $,
$ D_{6} = \mu_{k} $,
$ D_{3} = \beta_{k} + \alpha_{k - 1} \cdot \mu_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{7} = \zeta_{k} + \eta_{k - 1} \cdot \gamma_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{2} = \alpha_{k} + \beta_{k} \cdot \gamma_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{8} = \eta_{k} + \zeta_{k} \cdot \mu_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{1} = \beta_{k} \cdot \alpha_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{9} = \zeta_{k} \cdot \eta_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ D_{5} = \delta_{k} + \beta_{k} \cdot \zeta_{k} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} + \gamma_{k - 1} \cdot \mu_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1} + \alpha_{k - I} \cdot \eta_{k - I} \cdot \delta_{k - I}$.
Keeping in mind that we only need to solve for $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \mu, \zeta, \eta $, we equate some of the (non-constant) $ D_{i} $ to the corresponding elements of the matrix $ A $, we get the following:
$ \gamma_{k} = c_{k} $,
$ \mu_{k} = q_{k} $,
$ \beta_{k} = b_{k} - \alpha_{k - 1} \cdot \mu_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1}^{-1} $,
$ \zeta_{k} = f_{k} - \eta_{k - 1} \cdot \gamma_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1}^{-1} $,
$ \alpha_{k} = a_{k} - \beta_{k} \cdot \gamma_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ \eta_{k} = g_{k} - \zeta_{k} \cdot \mu_{k + I - 1} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} $,
$ \delta_{k} = d_{k} - \beta_{k} \cdot \zeta_{k} \cdot \delta_{k + I - 1}^{-1} - \gamma_{k - 1} \cdot \mu_{k - 1} \cdot \delta_{k - 1} - \alpha_{k - I} \cdot \eta_{k - I} \cdot \delta_{k - I}$.
For $ k $ outside the range $ [1, I{^2}] $, elements are to be treated as zeros.
The main question I have is, how do we solve this recursion? The recursion for $ \delta_{k} $ is the most confusing as we need the next $ \delta $ to solve for the previous one and so on.
